# JSON returned by ServiceStack is not parsed by JQuery

Tags: jquery, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack. A service is called by a client using jQuery.ajax. The service responds correctly, but the response fails to be parsed as JSON by jQuery. When debugging, I can see the service response is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Date: Mon, 15 Jul 2013 00:00:12 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.949 Unix/Mono
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private

bd
{"AccountId":"8bsrxeroshd", etc...}

0
```

The parse error in jQuery is "Unexpected token b".

From my web search it looks as though the extra response text 'bd' and the final '0' are concerned with chunked transfer encoding, but jQuery is unable to handle these during parsing.

Any suggestions on resolving this will be most welcome.

Comment: Have you looked into configuring nginx to not use chunked encoding?